# Time synchronization in Active directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, ntp

I've got issues with time synchronization in a domain. I have DCs that spans time zones, however the PDC is located in a time zone where daylight savings is active, this caused all the additional DCs and clients located in places where daylight savings is not active to roll back one hour....how can this issue be solved.

Regards.

Answer (score 8):

> I have DCs that spans time zones, however the PDC is located in a time zone where daylight 
>   savings is active, this caused all the additional DCs and clients
>   located in places where daylight savings is not active to roll back
>   one hour...

Can I uggest you have an admin (with knowledge) have a look at your machines? Something is SERIOUSLY WRONG with your timezone setup.

WIndows does not care about timezones - it has an internal clock that then gets translated into a visible "local time" when needed (and this translation is where the timezone comes in), but all timestamps are - if the machines are properly configured - totally ignorant to timezones.

Also, there is only one domain controller (the PDC Emulator) that is responsible for the time. I.e. he distributes it. Not that this is PDC Emulator - there is no PDC ever since I think Active Directory was created.

The only way i can see that happening what you describe is that the setup was done by someone totally ignorant of timezones and the machines actually are not in the correct timezones but a default one. If every machien would be - locally - set to their correct timezone, that would be a total non-issue as the machiens would ajust their presentation of the timestamps when summer/winter time changes (or not) and they would know when this happens.

Basically you run all servers in a specific timezone and then think they should magically ignore the timezone settings they have and show the correct time. The clients and additional DC's should have their timezone information updated so that they know their real timezone, not a fake one.

I again advice you have your AD checked by someone at least on junior admin level because if you bothered up that part then it is likely you have a ton of other issues - this is really "setting up a windows network 101" level.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that all clients and servers are in their respective time zones, all time zone patches are installed and that Windows is set to automatically adjust for daylight savings time.  Also ensure that you have a reliable time source.  See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10789900/1027551) for more info about that.

Answer (score -7):

I suggest you create sites for each different time zone.

Comment: How will that help?